# problem at rendering views using express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Though my rendering path is correct when I hit `http://localhost:4444/admin/posts/create` it shows some error like

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "/admin/posts/create" in views directory "D:\node practise\CMS\views"
```

**app.js** file is like

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cms', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(db => {
        console.log('MONGO CONNECTED!');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('MONGO NOT CONNECTED!');
    })



//making app to use static file
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//define template engine
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

//set default engine
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'home'}));

//load routes
const home = require("./routes/home/index");
const admin = require("./routes/admin/index");
const posts = require("./routes/admin/posts");

//use routes
app.use(home);
app.use("/admin", admin);
app.use("/admin/posts", posts);


//setting up server
app.listen(4444, () => {
    console.log('Listening....');
});
```

I have posts.js that handles this route like

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


router.all('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    req.app.locals.layout = 'admin';
    next();
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('It works!');
})

router.get('/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('/admin/posts/create');
})

module.exports = router;
```

And I have my views folder structure as
[image]

What may be the cause of error? When I try to send response it works but when I try to render the view it shows error.

Comment: is your index.js file (I suppose it's called like that) in your root folder?

Comment: No it is not inside root folder. I have folder called routes and inside this I have next directory called posts and inside this I have index.js file.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, that means that inside your router.get for /create you did not put good path for res.render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try `res.render('admin/posts/create');`?

If the view folders is set properly like this: `app.set('views', './views')`, you should be able to resolve simple view name like `res.render('myview')` under `./views` folder